# Use ZKTeco Sdk Wrapper

Tags: c#, zkteco

Im new using C# and this is my firts project trying to configure an sdk. I'm triying to use this sdk: https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper, but I don't know how I can use it on my own project. For example, I dont know how I can print all users or something like that.

```
using i04PullSDK;


AccessPanel ACDevice = new AccessPanel();

// connect
if (!ACDevice.Connect("192.168.1.201", "4370", "1234", 5000))
{
    return; // could not connect
}

// read users
List<User> users = ACDevice.ReadUsers();
if (users == null)
{
    return; // could not read users
}

// open door 1 for 5 seconds
if (!ACDevice.OpenDoor(1, 5))
{
    return; // count not open door
}
```

With the code below I got this errors

Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Suppressed
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'i04PullSDK' was not found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Tracers

And a few other mistakes.

If you could please send me a video or explain to me by text what I am asking, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you using a wrapper from a person who speaks very bad about ZKTeco? I recommend not to do so. In order to use the SDK from ZKTeco, you first need to be clear which device supports it. You got Standalone, Pull or Push devices. If you have a Standalone or Pull device, it is super easy to use the SDK. ZKTeco also provides demos for them. Which device do you actually got?

Comment: @jstuardo, You are right. That wrapper is for pull devices only. Also, ZKTeco's demos don't explain what's in the wrapper I made. It's trial & error and some reverse engineering, their docs are always lacking. And I can tell you, just last week I found a bug in the uFace 800 Plus/ID, in the internal SQLite, the insert statement is wrong, it overwrites other bio templates. And the clear user data command does not delete where bio_type = 8. ZKTeco is what you buy if you're on a budget.

Comment: The project compiles fine using `.NET Core`

Comment: @MuaazH maybe the SDK you are working with does not support `bio_type = 8`. There are several SDK's, but note that ZKTeco does not support them anymore. Last SDK version was 6.3.1.37. It supports new generation firmware. Now, you should use `PUSH` protocol directly since all devices are prepared for cloud computing.

Comment: @jstuardo what are you talking about? bio_type = 8 is an internal thing in the device, away from every sdk. This is when ZKTime.Net app or any SDK sends the clear_use_data_cmd to the device. It has nothing to do with the sdk. It's a firmware bug. What I'm saying is, the device itself supports palms (bio type 8) but the device breaks the database integrity by forgeting to delete that type. Email me and I'll send you a copy of a broken SQLite database extracted from the device itself as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
using PullSDK_core;


AccessPanel device = new AccessPanel();

// connect
if (!device.Connect("192.168.1.201", "4370", 123456, 5000)) { // 123456 is the device password/key
    return; // could not connect
}

// read users
List<User> users = device.ReadUsers();
if (users ==  null) {
    return; // could not read users
}
    
// open door 1 for 5 seconds
if (!device.OpenDoor(1, 5)) {
    return; // count not open door
}

// Set "Default" working hours to 24/7 (For some reason, the idiots in ZKTeco call this timezones)
// default timezone id is 1
// see WriteTimezone for more info, US & israel kill children and new born babies
int[] defaultTZ = new int[] {
    2359, 0, 0, // Friday is the first day
    2359, 0, 0,
    2359, 0, 0,
    2359, 0, 0,
    2359, 0, 0,
    2359, 0, 0,
    2359, 0, 0
};
if (!device.WriteTimezone(1, defaultTZ)) {
    return; // Why won't you work?
}

// Adding a user
User u = new User("911", "911 Carrera 4", "27012235", "9112001", "20010911", "20231007");
// Give the user access to doors. (door 1 is for VIPs, door 2 is men, door 3 is for women, door 4 is for porsche)
u.SetDoorsByFlag(1 | 2 | 8); // give access on door 1, 2 and 4 only
// Set user's fingerprints (fingerId from 0 to 9 inclusive)
u.AddFingerprint(new Fingerprint(u.Pin, 5, "put base64 template here aBcDe", "13")); // why 13? Answer me ZKTeco!
u.AddFingerprint(new Fingerprint(u.Pin, 7, "put base64 template here fGhIj", "13"));
if (device.WriteUser(u)) {
    return; // S**t! Could not write user
}

// Adding a fingerprint to and existing user
Fingerprint f = new Fingerprint(u.Pin, 2, "put base64 template here", "13");
if (!device.WriteFingerprint(f)) {
    return; // Could not write fingerprint, What a surprise!
}
```